# Issues encountered during the installation of boost

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I'm encountering an error during the installation of boost. After running `bootstrap.bat`, I proceeded to run `b2.exe`, but I receive the following error message:

```
error: '"g++" -dumpfullversion -dumpversion' returned an invalid $kind string '
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error or how to resolve it. Has anyone else encountered this issue before? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Updates: I've run the command `g++ -dumpfullversion -dumpversion` and the result is `8.1.0`. It seems that there are no abnormalities.

Comment: To help get an answer to your question it might be a good idea for you to run `g++ -dumpfullversion -dumpversion` yourself and tell us what it returns for you. Please do this and edit the question above to show what you got.

Comment: Do you actually *need* to build boost? Most of its libraries are header-only and can be used as-is.

Comment: The question is edited and show the result. It seems no abnormalities.